# Sveltekit - Access session from lib

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm using Sveltekit with Typescript. In `$lib` folder, I have an `api.ts` file.

After login, I'm writing JWT token to `session` and wanted to use it in `api.ts` file. But I'm getting an error.

I'm following this example:
 [sveltejs / realworld](https://github.com/sveltejs/realworld/blob/master/src/routes/login/index.svelte)

```js
// login.svelte

import { session } from "$app/stores";

// After login...

$session.accessToken = response.accessToken;
```

```js
// api.ts

import { session } from "$app/stores";

// Before sending request...

if ($session.accessToken) {
    // Add Bearer token to header...
}
```

Error: `Cannot find name '$session'. Did you mean 'session'?ts(2552)`

Why this `$session` thing works in `.svelte` file, but not in `.ts` file?

How can I access `accessToken` in `session` from `.ts`?

Thanks.

---

**Edit**

`api.ts` code:

```js
import { get as getStore } from "svelte/store";
import { session } from "$app/stores";

const base = "https://localhost:44300";

async function send(method: string, path: string, data?: unknown) {
  const opts = {
    method,
    headers: {},
    body: ""
  };

  if (data) {
    opts.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    opts.body = JSON.stringify(data);
  }

  const { accessToken } = getStore(session);

  if (accessToken) {
    opts.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
  }

  return fetch(`${base}${path}`, opts)
    .then((r) => r.text())
    .then((json) => {
      try {
        return JSON.parse(json);
      } catch (err) {
        return json;
      }
    });
}

export function get<T>(path: string): Promise<T> {
  return send("GET", path);
}

export function post<T>(path: string, data: unknown): Promise<T> {
  return send("POST", path, data);
}

export function put<T>(path: string, data: unknown): Promise<T> {
  return send("PUT", path, data);
}

export function del<T>(path: string, data: unknown): Promise<T> {
  return send("DELETE", path, data);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I want to add to the answer (but can't comment - lack of reput', so if it's inappropriate edit the actual answer to add the info, thanks); to Efe Erdogru and Raul Gomez:

The last line:

```
const { accessToken } = get(session);
```

cannot be at the top-level of the ts file. Do it in a function called from your Svelte file initialization block, so that at that point, the session is initialized.

Answer (score 2):

`$session` is a svelte-specific syntax [used to reactively access a store value](https://svelte.dev/docs#4_Prefix_stores_with_$_to_access_their_values). For one-time value access in a typescript file, use the [`get` function](https://svelte.dev/docs#get):

```
import { get } from 'svelte/store';
import { session } from "$app/stores";

const { accessToken } = get(session);
```

If you need a reactive solution, use `session.subscribe` instead.

Comment: Hi Connor, thanks for your answer. I've added `api.ts` content to the question. When I try it, I get "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Function called outside component initialization" error.

Comment: I can take a look, but you should open a new question if you have a new issue.

Comment: @EfeErdoğru did you figure this out? i am having the same problem